# Converting Mysql code to rails active record query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Need help in converting below mysql query to active record query.

```
    SELECT ad_trek_participant.id, ad_registration_data.id, ad_registration_data.email, ad_registration_data.first_name,ad_registration_data.last_name, ad_trek_participant.status, ad_trek_participant.payment_status, COUNT( * ) AS occurrences
FROM ad_trek_participant
INNER JOIN ad_registration_data ON ad_trek_participant.Registration_Data_Id = ad_registration_data.id
WHERE ad_trek_participant.status = '2'
AND ad_trek_participant.payment_status = '2'
GROUP BY ad_trek_participant.Email_Id
HAVING COUNT( * ) >=5
LIMIT 0 , 1000
```

The relationship between model is `has_one` and `belongs_to`

`ad_registration_data` 
`has_one :participation, foreign_key: "registration_data_id"`

`ad_trek_participant` 
`belongs_to :registration_data, foreign_key: "Registration_Data_Id"`

Comment: Yes, that is a query. Converting it depends on how your models are constructed and if those relationships are expressed properly (e.g. `has_many` and so forth).

Comment: @tadman updated the question please do check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Query worked for me good.

```
@participations = Participation.joins(:registration_data)
.where(payment_status:2,status:2)
.group("ad_registration_data.email")
.having("count(ad_registration_data.email)>=5")
.count('ad_registration_data.email')
```